# ¿Cómo agrupar un DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

he creado un dataframe donde resto las columnas Dentro(1) - Fuera(0) y después, lo que quiero es agruparlo por su nombre, en este caso, con la columna Frutas, pero no me doy una idea de como hacerlo, se supone que seria con la función groupby pero tengo un detalle, que al momento de agruparlas, me suma los tiempos de la columna Diff_time sumando los 4 tiempos del nombre.

este es el codigo que utilizo

```
#Importar librerias 
import pandas as pd
import datetime 

# Direccion del archivo xlsx
path = ("C:\\Users\\braya\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\Algoritmo y Metodologia\\ejemplo")

# Lectura del archivo
df = pd.read_excel("tiempos_exp.xlsx") #index_col = 0 

# Suma de tiempos por equipo
g = df.groupby(['Fruta'])['Diff_time'].sum()
#print(g) 

clase = pd.DataFrame(g)
print(clase)

# Exportar archivo formato excel 
g.to_excel("tiempos_exp2.xlsx", index = False)
```

el archivo de excel que estoy tratando es el siguiente, las celdas que están en amarillo, son las que se deben sumar, en este caso por fruta, tengo que tener un resultado parecido a esta tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, por favor agrega un ejemplo de cómo debería ser el `dataframe` al final

Comment: @HeytalePazguato listo